# is there any special script to insert into Oracle cluster table

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper, pls-00103

How to insert into oracle cluster tables and how to validate data inserted into that two tables correctly or not?

if I have two tables amp and dept.
these two table is cluster table and share same data blocks.
can I insert data into both table by simple insert statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I insert data into both table by simple insert statement.

Yes, using `INSERT ALL`, such as

```
insert all
  into emp (empno, ename) values (1, 'Little')
  into emp (empno, ename) values (2, 'Foot')
  --
  into dept (deptno, dname) values (100, 'IT')
select * from dual;
```

Comment: so how to validate that insertion or updation (dml operation) has successfully executed.

Comment: Using a SELECT?